# Options for supplying a custom popup to loginWithPopup auth0-react

Tags: auth0

I am reading the auth0-react documentation and I want to use the loginWithPopup method in a project. I have seen that the maintainers of the project discourage its use because of popup blocking add-ons and whatever and that is completely fine. I just want to see an example of providing a custom popup to it. I have searched the web and can't really say I am finding that many relevant examples besides this:
[Auth0 forums brief post](https://community.auth0.com/t/popupconfigoptions-custom-styles-for-popup-facebook-connection-specific/62595/2)

Anyone have any ideas or used it before in such a manner? Can I provide it with custom html of my own. It does not seem to work that way, but maybe I missing something or have used improper syntax. And the documentation having popup:any is not really helping me.